# Events are not called when changing visibility of an element

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I have a page that need to toggle the visibility of a div at regular interval. The issue is that the click events related to one of the parent element are often not called. If I stop the visibility toggle or if I slow it down (for example 300ms instead of 100ms) the click events are fired normally.

I have created a short example illustrating this issue.
You can test it here: http://threeds.me/0xC0DE/

Clicking the blue/red square should in theory fire the click event. When there is no animation (default behaviour here) clicking the blue square will always fire the onclick event. If you click on 'play/pause' the visibility of the red square will start to toggle every 100ms. When the animation is playing the click event is not call everytime you click on the square.

I would suspect that changing the visibility is somehow messing up with the DOM which as a result stop events for some milliseconds. I also tried to toggle the css visibility property to minimize the impact on the page but it has the same result.

But it's not only events. If I encapsulate the whole container in an  tag, clicking the element will not be always taking into account by the browser. So it's like that changing the visibility of a child element will make a parent blind for (quite) some time which I find really strange.

This issue is consistent with Firefox, Chrome and Opera (all on mac, cannot test ie) so it means there is something I don't get. So even if I don't get a solution, I would like to understand what is the problem.

Here the source for your immediate reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Wiggle problem</title>
<style>
#dback {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
#dfront {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var run = false;
function playpause() {
    if ( run ) {
        run = false;
    } else {
        run = true;
        update();
    }
}

function update() {
    if ( run==false ) {
        return;
    }

    var el = document.getElementById('dfront');
    if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        el.style.display = '';
    }

    setTimeout("update();", 100);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onclick="playpause();">play/pause</a>
<div id="container" onclick="d=new Date();t=d.getTime();document.getElementById('info').innerText='click '+t;">
    <div id="dback">
        <div id="dfront"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<span id="info"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really weird! However, I made some [tests](http://jsfiddle.net/svB3m/) and [fiddled with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/HqCnz/5/) a bit, and now I think it has nothing to do with bubbling (you can see on my test that clicks on elements with `visibility: hidden` bubble just fine).

Here is what I *think* could be going on: since your timer interval is so short, there is not enough time for an actual click to be registered – a click being a `mousedown` event, followed by a `mouseup` event, on the same element. What happens in your case is that `mouseup` is frequently being fired on the other element, not the same one that fired `mousedown`, and thus there is no `click` event. See the second link above, where I reduced the interval to 1 sec, and try to click on the blue square, and release the mouse button on the red square (or vice-versa). Nothing happens. I may be completely wrong, but that looks plausible.

I know this is not a solution, but you said:

> So even if I don't get a solution, I would like to understand what is the problem.

I hope this can help you find one!

Last but not least, a couple of side notes on your code:

1. The way you're calling `setTimeout` (passing a string) is not recommended, because it will force the use of [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) internally, and [`eval` should be avoided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21) as much as possible. Instead of passing the string with the function call code, just pass the function itself:

   ```
   setTimeout(update, 100);
   ```
2. It's considered a best practice today to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) (or [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)   for IE) to bind an event to an element, instead of using inline events like your `onclick="..."`. That has several advantages, like helping separate behavior, structure and layout, and making the event object automatically available to the event handler (as the first parameter to the handler function).

Comment: Thanks bfavaretto. I think you are right. This is logic and would explain why this is consistent on all browsers and behave like that even on links. I also really appreciate the advice. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

Acctually, when "dfront" is visible, its hovering over "container", and when you make a click, event goes to "dfront". but there is no onclick event, for "dfront" element.
Onclick event of "container" is not propagating on child elements - its normal, you can workaround it by using jquery it has "event propagation" option for events.
Or just set onclick event for "dfront".

Also you can create transparent layer over "container" and "dfront" and bind event to it.
Or, make onmouseclick event on window object, which will find out, if mouse position is over "dfront" by checking their coordinates and if true then event handler will be fired.

Comment: by default #dfront is visible and the onclick event on #container is properly fired because the event is propagating to the parents until one element stop the propagation. The problem seems to be that toggling the visibility affect this propagation. I was thinking about using some workarounds you mention but before doing it I want to make sure I understand the problem.

Comment: @Denis, propagation is not a jQuery feature, it's actually part of the DOM implementation, and is available in plain js (as well as the mechanisms for stopping event propagation).